# Why the output is not coming "5 5 5 5 5"?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = ""
  var i = 0;
  var n = i + 5;
  do {
    text += n - i + " ";
    i++;
  }
  while (i < 5);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code as long as i is less than 5.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to subtract next number from previous number in a series..
Cant figure out why output is "5 4 3 2 1".. Any ideas?? 
Why the output is not coming "5 5 5 5 5" ??

Thanks

Comment: because in the next line after you update `text` you're doing `i++;` ;) if you want it to stay 5 why don't you do: `text += n  + " ";`

Comment: Why do you expect the output to be `"5 5 5 5 5"`?

Comment: there are 5 numbers 1 2 3 4 5 now i want to take the output as (2-1) = 1, (3-2) = 1, (4-3)  = 1, (5-4) = 1..  i.e i am expecting  5 5 5 5 5 in this program because i want the output = current number -previous number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating your current number `n`. Put it inside `loop` and you'll get `5,5,5,5,5`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = ""
  var i = 0;
  var n;
  do {
    n = i + 5;
    text += n - i + " ";
    i++;
  }
  while (i < 5);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code as long as i is less than 5.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: But doing `n=i+5` and then printing `n-i` is clearly insensible. You are just printing 5, and the value of `i` is ignored

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating `i` so as to print it 5 times. 
However, you are ADDING `i` to the text as well,  and since `i` is changing each time the loop runs,  you were getting that result.

You should consider adding `n`,  whose value is 5, to get what you want.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = ""
  var i = 0;
  var n = i + 5;
  do {
    text += n+ " ";
    i++;
  }
  while (i < 5);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code as long as i is less than 5.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```